# Java: Need help on hashing function overflow

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, integer-hashing

I am working on an assignment were  I have to hash 10,000 numbers into a hash table of load size .1, .2 .3 .... up to .9. My problem is that my hashing function is giving me some overflow or something of the sort. If am doing a hash for a table with load factor of .5 like 36077(mod)20,000 it gives me 16070 as the key. This only happens on numbers that are above the load factor. This is the code for my hashing function.

```
    public int linearHash(int in){
    int hashKey = in%hashTableArray.length;
    while(this.hashTableArray[hashKey] != 0){
        hashKey += 1;
    }
    return hashKey;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: As @Reimeus said below, and also for Open Addressing `hashKey` should wrap around to zero if it reaches the end of the array. Watch you don't go into an infinite loop if the array is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking that you are exceeding the index bounds of the `hashTableArray` in your `while` loop. You could do:

```
while (hashKey < hashTableArray.length && this.hashTableArray[hashKey] != 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

Reimeus pointed out the OutOfBound problem and gave a solution. I just want to add something about your way to handle collision.

Your function looks like **open addressing** approach.  instead of `hashKey += 1;` perhaps you could consider to increment the `in`

```
 public int linearHash(int in){   
    int hashKey = in%hashTableArray.length;
    while(this.hashTableArray[hashKey] != 0){
        in ++;
        hashKey = in%hashTableArray.length;
    }
    return hashKey;
}
```

the example codes above didn't check for hashtable overflow. the auto-increment should not happen more than `hashTableArray.length` times. otherwise your program falls into dead loop

and please note that decide if a slot is free by checking `hashTableArray[hashKey] != 0` is not safe. for example, what about there are number `0` and `20000` in your elements.